Change Link Targets in iFrame
I have to use YouTrack in the company I am working for, and it drives me nuts for several reasons. I am now creating a Chrome Extension which helps me calm down a bit.
One of the absolutely ridiculous things is the fact, that YouTrack opens all Tickets in a new Tab. So one of the functions of my extension is overwriting the link targets. It all works fine except on these stupid widget things:

These are iframes (why tho??) and they block me from accessing it even though they are coming from the same source as the parent. So I have not found a way to get in there and change the link targets via JS / jQuery. Is there something I don't see?
I already tried removing the sandbox attribute but does not work. Here is how the iframe is loaded:

Any idea how I can access the dom of the iframe? Its all hosted on the same subdomain so theoretically cross-origin should not be a problem....
I obviously don't have access to the iframe's source code
function changeLinkTarget() {
    $('a').attr('target', '_self');
    document.querySelectorAll('iframe').forEach(iframe => {
        iframe.removeAttribute("sandbox");
        iframe.removeAttribute("allow");        
    });
$('iframe').contents().find('a').attr('target', '_self');
}

Logging $(iframe).contents() returns


How exactly is your extension working? You inject script into the page? If so, just do the same for the URL of the IFrame...

@Salketer Yes i Inject the code via domain matching:https://xxx.myjetbrains.com/*
But it does not work in the iframe even tho the iframe is located under the same domain
(xxx is our company identifier as anonymized i the screenshot above)

That's not what you are asking for, but in YouTrack, you can create your own widgets... For example, you can fork this widget, modify its code, and upload and use the new widget.
https://github.com/JetBrains/youtrack-issues-list-widget

@Filib I would double check your settings and what not, there is no reason you wouldn't be able to inject into the main document and not the IFRAME. Since it is your only hope, I suggest you dig into it and give details on how you are currently injecting the code so we can help make sure it injects into the iframe too.

Did you know you can double click on a card to open it in an overlay?
